# Necessity to commit immediately after using svn delete?

Tags: linux, svn

A 'build' directory in my project needs to be deleted and created again after every check out. 
Here is what I do which is kind of a long and cumbersome process and creates a large number of unnecessary commits:

```
$ svn delete build
$ svn commit -m "build directory deleted..." [Unnecessary commit]
$ svn update
$ mkdir build [to create a fresh empty directory of build]
$ cd build [perfom operations in build]
$ svn add build
$ svn commit -m "New revision having following XYZ changes"
```

**Problem:**
Is there a workaround to avoid the redundant commit just after delete? I just want to delete everything related to my project inside the 'build' directory to be deleted so that I may create new versions of them. Following steps, which I thought should have worked, give problems

```
$ svn delete build
$ rm -r build
$ mkdir build
$ svn add build
$ svn commit -m "New revision having following XYZ changes"
```

Comment: So you need that `build` directory does not inherit change history from previous releases?

Comment: that will be a yes. I think what Chaitanya Gupta proposed looks good, but running the build script can take upto 10 mins to make the directory. I would like to have a work-around, if possible, to avoid that overhead

Comment: I think I am missing something here -- you don't need to run a build script to make the build directory. Why not just use `mkdir`? Typically, build scripts create a build directory if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Chaitanya svn:ignore has done the job for me. Thanks to you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A build directory is not something you typically want in a repository. What you should ideally be doing is 1) Ignore the build directory from svn using the `svn:ignore` property, 2) remove or create the build directory using your build script

This way you will also avoid having any (needless) commits in your repository which just create or remove the build directory.

Comment: Running the build script can take upto 10 mins to make the directory. I would like to have a work-around, if possible, to avoid that overhead.

Comment: See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional approach is to check out and build, but not commit the resulting build artefacts. Instead, create a tag (in svn, you do this with svn cp, customarily to tags/_build_id_). If you need to keep track of what compiler version etc was used for the build, you can generate and commit a text file with the necessary information. This way, you can - at least in theory - regenerate an identical build if you ever need to. Copying the build artefacts to a separate archive is still a goid idea, but this is usually not kept under version control.

Answer (score 0):

From your svn commands I guess that you want to commit a version of the code without the local build directory, then update from the svn repo (also without the build dir), but then re-create the "build" directory and save it the repository.

If the build directory *must* be re-created after each "svn update" (e.g. because something changed due to the "svn update") then you can use the *svn ignore* to ignore the "build" dir on the first commit, but can't escape re-creating it.

If you *can re-use* the old "build" directory after the "svn update", you can save time by setting and resetting the svn ignore property before/after the commits:

```
$ svn propset svn:ignore build
$ svn commit -m "build directory deleted..." [Unnecessary commit]
$ svn update    
$ svn propdel svn:ignore build
$ svn commit -m "New revision having following XYZ changes"
```

I haven't tried it myself, but it should work :)